# Fantasy film about flying creatures and learning how to ride or command them

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember being about 12 (2003 +/- 5 years) and watching a movie with my dad about flying creatures (maybe birds, dragons, hippogryphs) and a big part of the plot was learning how to ride or command them and maybe using long leather gloves.

For some reason I think that David Thewlis was in it, but when I look at his IMDb, nothing seems to match it. I feel like the animals had to "choose" you, but I also suspect my memory is leaking from related things like hippogryphs in Harry Potter. It was live actors (not animated).

Comment: Could it have been a TV series? Dinotopia is from 2002, and protagonist David Scott (Wentworth Miller) being partnered with a Pteranodon as a pilot is a big plot point.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Wow, so I definitely saw that and it was creeping in my subconscious. Maybe that's where I got David Thewlis. I keep thinking of this scene when they are on a mountaintop/mountainside and they are training to ride these animals (birds, dragons, something). Sorry my memory is so bad.

Comment: Honorable mention to *Avatar* ([that scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2_RF3KXuSQ)), I'd be pretty surprised if it turned out to be that though. Live action, sure, but most of the people are kind of blue, which I don't think is forgettable :-)

Comment: @Jenayah Oh wow memory is weird; I may have added that scene into Dinotopia in my mind. Fairly sure it is Dinotopia now (with hints of Avatar and Harry Potter); I'll be watching this weekend to verify.

Comment: Might it be *Eragon*? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eragon_(film)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @EikePierstorff for pointing out [Dinotopia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinotopia_(miniseries)). I believe I saw that when I was 11 and my mind injected memories of some other movies, but Dinotopia definitely has the theme and setting that I was trying to remember.

Answer (score 2):

[How to Train Your Dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_Train_Your_Dragon_(film)) is a 2010 animated film, a good 1/3 of which covers the main character learning how to ride his Dragon with an injured wing, and how to interact with other wild dragons to the point where they will accept riders.

This happens against the background belief that Dragons are dangerous pests that can only be killed or avoided.

There's no leather gloves, but Hiccup (the main character) invents a series of devices to compensate for Toothless' (the dragon) missing tail wing.

The kids don't really "choose" their dragons per se, but they are paired up with ones with similar qualities in a fairly typical fantasy story manner. Big guy with Big Dragon, twins with a two headed dragon, and so on.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: @GregSchmit I assume someone thinks it is wrong. Which it might well be judging by the comment train on the question.

Comment: Yeah but my question was so ridiculously vague.

Comment: I'm the downvoter, @Greg, for the exact reason Jontia presumed above: the question might be vague, but HTTYD is by no way a match. It's animated and not live action, for starters, the dragons don't choose you, the bit about leather gloves is too far-fetched, and the  date doesn't fit either.

Comment: @Jenayah all good points, but I have seen really out there things be right before. And I am all about answers > comment answers.